# how to understand mpmc = N x mpsc

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency

In the equation: `mpmc = mpmc = N x  mpsc` , what's `N` represented for? If it could be thread count?

I know `GMP` concurrent model in Go programming language is an implementation of `mpmc`. But I don't understand what is `mpsc`. What I know about it is: A thread maintains a unique queue internally.

Much appreciate if there's any resources provided to introduce `mpsc`.